# ¿Cómo puedo mapear un array de objetos en react?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Estoy implementando una practica para mostrar los datos obtenidos del Backend y mapearlos.Tengo el siguiente array de objetos con el que realizo mis pruebas:

```
const test = [
    {id: 10, value: "Tema1", },
    {id: 20, value: "Tema2", },
    {id: 30, value: "Tema3", },
    {id: 40, value: "Tema4", },
];
```

Lo mapeo de la siguiente forma:

```
{test.map(({id, value}) => (
  <p key={id}>
   {value}
  </p>
 ))}
```

Todo resulta correcto, pero cuando quiero mapear los datos que me llegan del Backend, no los muestra. Así obtengo los datos:

```
const response = await GetTopics(); // Respuesta del Backend
arrayTopics = response.data.topics; // Obtengo array
console.log(arrayTopics);
```

Este es el array que imprime:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un array de arrays, lo que quiero hacer es tener los datos por **'id'** y **'value'** como en mi variable **test y mapearlos**, pero no resulta, esto es lo que tengo para intentar darle esa forma:

```
const response = await GetTopics(); // Respuesta del Backend
arrayTopics = response.data.topics; // Obtengo array
console.log(arrayTopics):

// Continua el código...
const topics = [];
for(let element of arrayTopics){
   topics.push({ id: element[0], value: element[1]},)
}
console.log(topics)
```

Después de realizar el código anterior obtengo un array de objetos, igualito a mi variable test:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al mapearlos no me muestra nada, es como si estuviera vacio. Agradeceria mucho cualquier aportación, no me cierro a aprender otras formas de solucionarlo. Gracias por su tiempo :)

Comment: `topics` debe ser una variable de estado en el componente, hay que hacer el set correspondiente, luego se mapea `topics` justo como haces con `test`

Comment: con los estados lo intente de esta forma: const [ topics, setTopics ] = useState( [] ); y en vez de usar el push lo cambio por el setTopics: setTopics( [ { id: element[0], value: element[1] } ] ) pero solo me muestra el ultimo y mi variable topics se queda vacia, como si no hubiera agregado nada

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar  tu array que llega desde tu backend para poder hacer unas pruebas, tal vez necesitas usar `Object.keys`

Comment: Ya esta incluida la imagen del array que llega desde mi backend bro. Es la primera imagen que adjunto. Es un array de arrays lo que llega

Comment: @JoseMiguelLopez me refiero a que pegues el código de la imagen, no es necesario usar imágenes en este caso, porque son JSON diferentes al que pones al inicio y el de tu imagen

Comment: @Daniel ya actualice la pregunta. Espero asi sea mas entendible, asi obtengo los array y asi se imprimen, gracias por el apoyo

Comment: @JoseMiguelLopez el problema es que tu array que pones de ejemplo es diferente al que muestras en la foto, por eso te pedía de favor que evitaras usar imágenes y pegaras el código, con el for estás volviendo agregar el array, y eso lo conviertes en `Object`, ahí puedes usar `Object.keys`, porque la primera imagen muestra un `array`, al usar el for, se convierte en `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría lo siguiente:

```javascript
import {useState} from 'react';

const response = await GetTopics(); // Respuesta del Backend
arrayTopics = response.data.topics;

//Inicializamos el valor de test con arrayTopics
const [test, setTest] = useState(arrayTopics)

{
  test.map((t) => {
   return (
    <p key={t.id}>
     {t.value}
    </p>
   )
})}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar asi como usted sugiere, pero no muestra nada, creo es porque estoy pasando directamente el array que me llega y no asigno el id y value